# Different game modes for Thunderstone

Tags: house-rules, deck-building

While plenty entertaining in the original version, the game **Thunderstone** looks like it could be played in many more ways.
Besides the most obvious modifications like playing with more (or less) monster, item or hero classes, what are the most popular/best modes? I'm interested in single- as well as multi-player ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of variants listed in the rulebooks ([Wrath of the Elements, in particular, has solo play and epic variants printed in it among others](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/file/download/5lnezl7kbf/AEG-TS-Wrath-Rulebook.pdf)).  Having tried most of them out, I have to say that I still greatly prefer just the basic scenario.  In particular, the small size of the Village stacks means that any longer variants tend to turn into just grinding towards the end, as there is little purchasing one can do once the premium Village stacks are exhausted.